# Travelling Salesman Problem with visualisation in Java

Tags: java, swing, traveling-salesman

For practicing purposes, I challenged myself to write a program that solves the TSP and visualises the results step by step.

As for now, my program uses a simple nearest neighbour algorithm. I want my program to be flexible, so when I add a new algorithm, it will be able to visualise the results, too, without messing with the logic of display.

One of the problems I encountered was displaying the solution step by step. I solved it by creating multiple partial solutions, storing them, and displaying one after another. I feel like it can be done better, but I am not really good in graphics, so I hope to get some clues here.

The `Point` class represents a city:

```
class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point(){
        Random r = new Random();
        x=r.nextInt(1000);
        y=r.nextInt(650);
    }

    public double calculateDistanceToPoint(Point p) {
        double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x-p.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y-p.y, 2));
        return round(dist,2);
    }

    private static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }
}
```

Then, the `Solver` class, which is doing calculations:

```
class Solver {
    //list of all points to visit
    private static ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

    //adjacency matrix
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> adjMatrix = new ArrayList<>();

    //found solution
    private static ArrayList<Point> solution = new ArrayList<>();

    //visited points
    private ArrayList<Integer> visitedPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    //used for visualisation
    private static Solution finalSolution = new Solution();

    public void clear() {
        points.clear();
        solution.clear();
        visitedPoints.clear();
        adjMatrix.clear();
        finalSolution.clear();
    }

    public void addPoint(Point p) {
        points.add(p);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Point> getPoints() {
        return Solver.points;
    }

    public void fillAdjacencyMatrix() {
        int iter_x;
        int iter_y;
        for (iter_x = 0; iter_x < points.size(); iter_x++) {
            ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (iter_y = 0; iter_y < points.size(); iter_y++) {
                if (iter_x == iter_y) {
                    temp.add(-1.0);
                } else {
                    temp.add(points.get(iter_x).calculateDistanceToPoint(points.get(iter_y)));
                }
            }
            adjMatrix.add(temp);
        }
    }

    private int getIndexOfMin(ArrayList<Double> arr) {
        Double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        int index = -2;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            Double val = arr.get(i);
            if (!(val == -1.0) && !visitedPoints.contains(i) && val < min) {
                min = val;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    public void solveUsingNN(int startingPoint) {
        int noOfVisited = 0;

        //find nearest point from the starting one
        int nearest = getIndexOfMin(adjMatrix.get(startingPoint));
        Solution sol = new Solution();

        //until we've visited all points
        while (noOfVisited!=points.size()) {
            //get next nearest point and add it to visited
            nearest = getIndexOfMin(adjMatrix.get(nearest));
            visitedPoints.add(nearest);

            //add this point to solution
            Point newPoint = points.get(nearest);
            solution.add(newPoint);

            //create a new frame for animation, containing all previous steps and recently added one
            SolutionStep ss = new SolutionStep();
            Point p;
            for (Point newPoint : solution) {
                p = new Point(newPoint.getX(), newPoint.getY());
                ss.addPoint(p);
            }
            sol.addStep(ss);
            noOfVisited++;
        }
        finalSolution=sol;
    }
}
```

Then, the `SolutionStep` class:

```
class SolutionStep{
    public final ArrayList<Point> step = new ArrayList<>();
    public SolutionStep(){}

    public void addPoint(Point p){
        step.add(p);
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            for (int i = 0; i < step.size()-1; i++) {
                g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(step.get(i).getX(), step.get(i).getY(), step.get(i + 1).getX(), step.get(i + 1).getY()));
        }
    }
}
```

And `Solution`, which contains many steps.

```
public class Solution {
    private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<SolutionStep> playbackSolution = new ArrayList<>();
    private int noOfFrames;

    public Solution(ArrayList<SolutionStep> listOfSteps, int noOfFrames){
        this.noOfFrames=noOfFrames;
        playbackSolution=listOfSteps;
    }
    public Solution(){}

    public static ArrayList<SolutionStep> getPlayback(){
        return playbackSolution;
    }
    public void clear(){
        playbackSolution.clear();
    }

    public void addStep(SolutionStep solutionStep){
        playbackSolution.add(solutionStep);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        int numberOfPoints;
        points = Solver.getPoints();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        //draw all points
        for (Point point : points) {
            g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(point.getX(), point.getY(), 6, 6));
        }

        //draw next line
        for(int i = 0;i<noOfFrames;i++) {
            playbackSolution.get(i).draw(g);
        }

        //if we are at the final solution, draw a line from last point to the first
        if (noOfFrames == points.size()){
            numberOfPoints = points.size();
            Point first = playbackSolution.get(0).step.get(0);
            Point last = playbackSolution.get(numberOfPoints-1).step.get(numberOfPoints-1);
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(first.getX(), first.getY(), last.getX(), last.getY()));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the visualisation:

```
   public class MainFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                MainFrame f = new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private TSPDrawer tsp;

    public MainFrame() {
        tsp = new TSPDrawer();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Start Simulation");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tsp.startSimulation(true);
            }
        });
        panel.add(tsp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public class TSPDrawer extends JPanel {

        private Timer timer;
        private int displayNoOfSteps = 0;
        public Solution solution = null;
        private int noOfFrames;
        public TSPDrawer() {
            setOpaque(false);
            timer = new Timer(80, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    solution = new Solution(Solution.getPlayback(),displayNoOfSteps);
                    noOfFrames = Solver.getPoints().size();
                    if (displayNoOfSteps<noOfFrames+1) {
                        repaint();
                        displayNoOfSteps++;
                    }
                    else
                        startSimulation(false);
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(1000, 600);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (!(solution==null)) {
                solution.draw(g);
            }
        }

        public void startSimulation(boolean run) {
            if (run){
                displayNoOfSteps=0;
                tsp.removeAll();
                Solver s = new Solver(100);
                s.solveUsingNN(0);
                timer.start();
            }
            else {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm using too much static fields and methods- but on the other hand, would it be better to create instances of, for example, `Solver` and then have non-static methods to get the solutions?

As I mentioned earlier, I want to get some feedback on this code before I write more complex algorithms, such as simulated annealing, so it would be easy to maintain good code quality.

I know it's quite a bit of code, so thank you for reading and analyzing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I feel like I'm using too much static fields and methods- but on the other hand, would it be better to create instances of, for example, Solver and then have non-static methods to get the solutions?

Sure! About the only sane reason for using static is a utility class like `java.lang.Math`. A static class with mutable state like yours is a sin. Just imagine two threads trying to solve a TSP at the same time.

### Point

```
class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;
```

I see that your `Point` is immutable. That's a good decision, but then also declare `x` and `y` as `final`. This makes your class thread-safe and makes the immutability obvious.

```
    public Point(){
        Random r = new Random();
        x=r.nextInt(1000);
        y=r.nextInt(650);
    }
```

Creating a `Random` instance for a single use doesn't feel right. With

```
    public Point(Random random) {
        x = random.nextInt(SCREEN_WIDTH);
        y = random.nextInt(SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    }
```

you allow the user to make their random TSP reproducible (by seeding the `random`). Note also the spacing and constants.

```
    public double calculateDistanceToPoint(Point p) {
        double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x-p.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y-p.y, 2));
        return round(dist,2);
    }
```

Most of the time, any rounding outside of presentation is wrong.

```
private static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

This looks rather inefficient, but that's fine for your case. I'd simply go for

```
private static double roundToTwoPlaces(double value) {
    return 0.01 * Math.round(100 * value);
}
```

as it's much simpler and good enough. Still, I can't see what you gain by this rounding...

### Solver

```
class Solver {
    //list of all points to visit
    private static ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
```

Either use proper javadoc or leave it out. I guess everyone knowing TSP will thing that the `points` are to be visited. Maybe you should call it `pointsToBeVisited`.. probably no, too long and too small added value. Maybe `cities`? Or just leave it as is.

But always use `List` instead of `ArrayList` in declarations. Here, it rather doesn't matter, but in a parameter list it would.

```
//adjacency matrix
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> adjMatrix = new ArrayList<>();
```

Again, either `adjMatrix` is clear enough (to me it is) or name it `adjacencyMatrix`.

Consider using an array here as you never need it to grow. An `double[][]` is quite a bit faster as you need no autoboxing.

```
    //used for visualisation
    private static Solution finalSolution = new Solution();
```

This should ideally be not there. Maybe adding a callback (e.g., a `Callable<Solution>`) to be called after each step would help.

```
    public static ArrayList<Point> getPoints() {
        return Solver.points;
    }
```

By returning the internal list, you allow everyone who gets it to manipulate it later. So everything may happen and you've lost any encapsulation. Either return a copy, or provide `getPoint(int index)`, or just leave it out.

```
    public void fillAdjacencyMatrix() {
        int iter_x;
        int iter_y;
        for (iter_x = 0; iter_x < points.size(); iter_x++) {
            ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (iter_y = 0; iter_y < points.size(); iter_y++) {
```

No, please. No `iter_x` as underscore shouldn't be used except in constant names. No declaration before the loop as the scope should always be minimized. I'd go for

```
    public void fillAdjacencyMatrix() {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < points.size(); ix++) {
            List<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int iy = 0; iy < points.size(); iy++) {
```

if I really wanted to make the correspondence between `ix`/`iy` and `x`/`y` clear.... but there's no `x` and `y` there. So use just plain `i` and `j`. It caries no information and this is fine as there's no information to carry.

```
                if (iter_x == iter_y) {
                    temp.add(-1.0);
```

This doesn't feel right. The distance from a point to itself is 0 not -1. Ideally, you should never need such a distance. Leave out this branch if you can.

```
private int getIndexOfMin(ArrayList<Double> arr) {
    Double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
```

Don't use `Double` when you need `double`.

```
    int index = -2;
```

Why not -3? ...

```
        SolutionStep ss = new SolutionStep();
        Point p;
        for (Point newPoint : solution) {
            p = new Point(newPoint.getX(), newPoint.getY());
```

Declare `p` in the right place, i.e., two lines down. You save one line and do the right thing.

---

*I've got lazy...*